# vCSA 5.5 vPostgres backup routine

Tags: postgresql, vmware, database-backups, vsphere, vcenter

I would like to save a bourne shell **script** in **/etc/cron.*** on vCenter server virtual appliance 5.5 to backup the vpostgres (VMware vCenter postgresql database).

[VMware knowledge base article 2034505](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2034505%E2%80%8E) recommend stopping vpxd service before backing up.
I suppose to prevent backing up the database in an inconsistent state (while vcenter operations are running).

However the [official PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/continuous-archiving.html) precises :
<<3.Perform the backup, using any convenient file-system-backup tool such as tar or cpio (not pg_dump or pg_dumpall). It is neither necessary nor desirable to stop normal operation of the database while you do this.>>

My questions are:

- Do I need to stop VMWare Composer and vpxd services prior to backing up the DB ?
- If not can I use cpio to back it up without stopping the services ? how ?

PostgreSQL or VMware experts answers preferred please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may notice that [this script](https://web.archive.org/web/20160122054619/http://bidabe.zapto.org/?p=360) does not stop VPXD services for backing up the database. It is because the official PostgreSQL documentation precises : “**pg_dump** is a utility for backing up a PostgreSQL database. It **makes consistent backups even if the database is being used concurrently**“.

https://web.archive.org/web/20160122054619/http://bidabe.zapto.org/?p=360